# Can't find elements on page

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an element I can't find on my page. 
Actually, I can't find any of the elements on this page. 
I have successfully moved to the `IFrame` , but can't find any of the elements.
The Frmae's Id is : `kendoIFrame` and one of the elements I can't find is:

```html
<div class="k-widget k-splitter" id="divAll" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; touch-action: none;" data-role="splitter">
```

I have tried to find the element as follow:

```
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
 var Gisbutton = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("btnGis")));
 Gisbutton.Click();
_webdriver.SwitchTo().Window(_webdriver.WindowHandles.ToList().Last());
 new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("kendoIFrame"));
var element = _webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("divAll"));
```

Looks like I can switch to the frame since I'm not getting an error on it, but when trying to find element, I'm getting the following error:
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with id == divAll`

FYI, there is only one IFrame in this specific html page.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is an internal website.

Comment: You can with adding more wait, 5 seconds is very minimal. try with 30 seconds atleast

Comment: same result, even if waiting 60 seconds

Comment: Can you share the html screenshot of the page

Comment: Can you call this `driver.findElement(By.id("kendoIFrame")).findElements(By.xpath("//*"))` and check weather the element you are looking forward is there or not. Its in java and sorry for that

Comment: You should try this after switching the frame

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: The image is just an additional information , according to someone's request here. I have published my code trials and the error i'm experiencing. In general, I agree that screenshot as the only information source is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in an iframe, you need to switch to that iframe first, then search. Something like:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iFrameTitle")));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per *Best Practices* you should switch to an `<iframe>` when it is available and then try to locate the elements within the `<iframe>` through either of the methods :

- [*`FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt Method (String)`*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt_1.htm) : An expectation for checking whether the given frame is available to switch to. If the frame is available it switches the given driver to the specified frame.
- [*`FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt Method (By)`*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt.htm) : An expectation for checking whether the given frame is available to switch to. If the frame is available it switches the given driver to the specified frame.

  Solution

  ---

You need to switch to the frame with proper wait and then locate the element as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("kendoIFrame"));
var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.k-widget.k-splitter#divAll"));
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm still getting an error. `Unable to find element with css selector == div.k-widget.k-splitter#divAll`

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code block and the error stack trace for further analysis?

Comment: Sure no problem

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to a `<iframe>` first

driver.switchTo().Frame("iFrameName"); //switching the frame

Then try to find element

driver.findElement(By.xpath("ElementXPath")).click(); // To find element